# ACE-Editor autocomplete whole sentences

Tags: autocomplete, code-snippets, ace-editor, gherkin

I'm trying to get the ACE editor to show auto suggestions for BDD (Gherkin) based stories. Assuming that I have a way to generate a list of snippets in the form

```
snippet Given a certain precondition with a parameter $aParam is fullfilled
     Given a certain precondition with a parameter ${1:aParam} is fullfilled
```

I do get a nice list of auto suggestions when entering one of words of the first line, however, spaces do stop the auto completion and it restarts with the next word.

Is there a way to get the autocompletion to consider the entire line, except just one word at a time?